# Cross -Compiling speex library for ios

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, arm

Actually, I have the source code of `speex` library. Its written in c. I want to compile it for the `arm` architecture so that i can add it and work with my iPad project. When i am compiling the source in my mac its compiling it for the `i386` architecture that cannot be used with the arm architecture.

How can i compile the source for arm architecture?

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to create a new "library" project, add the speex source, and get it to compile. This library project is an iOS library of course. Once you can get it to compile, you can then add that project to your primary project, and it will work in both the Simulator and the device.

When you add library projects to a main project, you have to set a dependency in the target, and add a path to the headers - but you can find many Q&A discussions on how to do this on SO.

The most difficult part of this is probably getting the config.h file (whatever) that the .configure script builds. You can probably take the one that was generated and most likely it will work just fine.

EDIT: BTW, Speex is outdated - there is a replacement Opus - see [the Speex site](http://www.speex.org)