# Compile Speex on xCode for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, speex

I'm trying to compile and use the Speex codec for an iPhone app. I've used several tutorials:
http://codeforfun.wordpress.com/2010/04/29/compile-speex-for-iphone/

Also tried to compile it with this suggestion:
[Cross -Compiling speex library for ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12033437/cross-compiling-speex-library-for-ios)

and offcourse change the "SDKROOT" to "iphoneos"

all of this got me to a problem that I cannot really create binary files. I think I've tried everything!
I think the issue is something about makefile missing. I've changed the original Makefile.in to a "makefile" and now xCode can find it but still it doesn't work.

The error I get is : d: warning: directory not found for option '-L.../CSource/libspeex/.libs'
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_speex_nb_mode", referenced from:
      -[MainViewController viewDidLoad] in MainViewController.o

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it, but here is the Speex library precompiled for iOS: https://github.com/iosdevzone/IDZPrecompiledSpeex